# What's the best way to zero a mill using a hole on the SIDE of the part

Tags: machining, cnc

Lets say I have a block of metal clamped in a vice on my mill, and that part has a hole in the face that's facing me (parallel to the Y axis).

What's the best way to zero the X axis on that hole? The hole diameter is about 6mm

The only way I can think of is to first locate the hole relative to a flat surface, and then zero the mill on that surface. I figure that's not ideal due to relying on the surface accuracy, and tolerance stack up. It would be really nice to zero on the hole directly. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly using another datum is probably the simplest way... (Assuming once you do the tolerance stack calcs, that the possible deviation is within acceptable limits...)

Since you are asking to use the hole as a datum, however, I'm assuming it has a precise fit/tolerance. If so you could consider a precision dowel fitted into the hole, and then touch off both outside faces of that dowel, before splitting the difference to find the centre.